# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'Runme' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I've been bug checking this for a while, but I still cant figure out whats wrong. It's supposed to take my grades, and spit out my allowance. It was working before, but JSfiddle messed it up, and now it's having OTHER problems. Can anyone tell what's wrong?
Code:

```
<head>
<script>
alert('loaded');
function Runme() {
    alert("running");
    document.forms["form"].Runme();
    var Mathematics = document.personal.Mathematics;
    var OMathematics = document.personal.OMathematics;
    var Sci = document.personal.Sci;
    var OSci = document.personal.OSci;
    var ELA = document.personal.ELA;
    var OELA = document.personal.OELA;
    var SS = document.personal.SS;
    var OSS = document.personal.OSS;
    var Elec1 = document.personal.Elec1;
    var OElec1 = document.personal.OElec1;
    var Elec2 = document.personal.Elec2;
    var OElec2 = document.personal.OElec2;
    var Elec3 = document.personal.Elec3;
    var OElec3 = document.personal.OElec3;
    var Elem1 = document.personal.Elec1;
    var OElem1 = document.personal.OElec1;
    var Elem2 = document.personal.Elec2;
    var OElem2 = document.personal.OElec2;
    var Elem3 = document.personal.Elec3;
    var OElem3 = document.personal.OElec3;
    var Owed = 0;
    var Calc = function(n, o) {
        if (n >= 90) {
            Owed = Owed + 1;
            if (n >= 95) {
                Owed = Owed + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (owed >= 80) {
            Owed = Owed + 0.5;
        }
        if (n > o) {
            Owed = Owed + 0.5;
        }
        if (n < o) {
            if (n > 95) {
                Owed = Owed - 0.25;
            }
        }
    };
    Calc(Mathematics, OMathematics);
    Calc(Sci, OSci);
    Calc(ELA, OELA);
    Calc(SS, OSS);
    Calc(Elec1, Elec1);
    Calc(Elec2, Elec2);
    Calc(Elec3, Elec3);
    Calc(Elem1, Elem1);
    Calc(Elem2, Elem2);
    Calc(Elem3, Elem3);
    alert(Owed);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
<!--form name="form" action="grades.pl" onsubmit="return checkscript()"-->
<h5>Math</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Mathematics>
<h5>Old Math</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OMathematics>
<h5>Science</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Sci>
<h5>Old Science</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OSci>
<h5>English</h5><input type=text size=20 name=ELA>
<h5>Old English</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OELA>
<h5>Social Studies</h5><input type=text size=20 name=SS>
<h5>Old Social Studies</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OSS>
<h5>Elective One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec1>
<h5>Old Elective One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec1>
<h5>Elective Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec2>
<h5>Old Elective Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec2>
<h5>Elective Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elective Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
<h5>Elem One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elem One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
<h5>Elem Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elem Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
<h5>Elem Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elem Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
</form>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit and Calculate" onClick="Runme()"/>
</center>

</body>
```

Comment: wrong? tell us. Syntax error, wrong result. what?

Comment: @Valamas The current one is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'Runme' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you need a `<form>` element, which has obviously been commented out.

Other notes:
Make sure you use the same case throughout. "Owed" != "owed".
onClick should be "onclick", although most browsers let it work.

```
<head>
<script>
    //alert('loaded');
function Runme() {
    //    alert("running");
    //document.forms["personal"].Runme();
    var Mathematics = document.personal.Mathematics;
    var OMathematics = document.personal.OMathematics;
    var Sci = document.personal.Sci;
    var OSci = document.personal.OSci;
    var ELA = document.personal.ELA;
    var OELA = document.personal.OELA;
    var SS = document.personal.SS;
    var OSS = document.personal.OSS;
    var Elec1 = document.personal.Elec1;
    var OElec1 = document.personal.OElec1;
    var Elec2 = document.personal.Elec2;
    var OElec2 = document.personal.OElec2;
    var Elec3 = document.personal.Elec3;
    var OElec3 = document.personal.OElec3;
    var Elem1 = document.personal.Elec1;
    var OElem1 = document.personal.OElec1;
    var Elem2 = document.personal.Elec2;
    var OElem2 = document.personal.OElec2;
    var Elem3 = document.personal.Elec3;
    var OElem3 = document.personal.OElec3;
    var Owed = 0;
    var Calc = function(n, o) {
        if (n >= 90) {
            Owed = Owed + 1;
            if (n >= 95) {
                Owed = Owed + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (Owed >= 80) {
            Owed = Owed + 0.5;
        }
        if (n > o) {
            Owed = Owed + 0.5;
        }
        if (n < o) {
            if (n > 95) {
                Owed = Owed - 0.25;
            }
        }
    };
    Calc(Mathematics, OMathematics);
    Calc(Sci, OSci);
    Calc(ELA, OELA);
    Calc(SS, OSS);
    Calc(Elec1, Elec1);
    Calc(Elec2, Elec2);
    Calc(Elec3, Elec3);
    Calc(Elem1, Elem1);
    Calc(Elem2, Elem2);
    Calc(Elem3, Elem3);
    alert(Owed);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
<form name="personal" action="grades.pl">
<h5>Math</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Mathematics>
<h5>Old Math</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OMathematics>
<h5>Science</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Sci>
<h5>Old Science</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OSci>
<h5>English</h5><input type=text size=20 name=ELA>
<h5>Old English</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OELA>
<h5>Social Studies</h5><input type=text size=20 name=SS>
<h5>Old Social Studies</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OSS>
<h5>Elective One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec1>
<h5>Old Elective One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec1>
<h5>Elective Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec2>
<h5>Old Elective Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec2>
<h5>Elective Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elective Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
<h5>Elem One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elem One</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
<h5>Elem Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elem Two</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
<h5>Elem Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=Elec3>
<h5>Old Elem Three</h5><input type=text size=20 name=OElec3>
</form>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit and Calculate" onclick="Runme()"/>
</center>

</body>
```

Comment: @AidanEdwards That's because you're passing references to DOM elements, when you need to get their values (and compare them).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.forms["form"].Runme();
> ```

will fail because there's no such form and it wouldn't have a `Runme` method anyway.

> ```
> document.personal...
> ```

will fail because there is no such thing.

Try getting rid of the reference to the bogus form, and replace all uses of

```
document.personal.inputName
```

with

```
document.getElementsByName("inputName")[0].value
```

Comment: @AidenEdwards, could you be more specific about which part of my answer you found lacking?  You asked what was wrong, and I answered that.